# ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)) after upgrade to Rails 4 and Ruby 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, ruby-on-rails-4

I upgraded from Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 3.0.9 to Ruby 2 and Rails 4.0.2.

An error occurs when I refresh the web page localhost:3000. I tried to remove all layout code applicaton.html.erb, and application.rb controller code to rule out any change of Ruby or Rails version. In console, I can't see anything other than the backtrace

This crash is in Linux with Oracle, with Mac and Postgress local database goes fine.

The error occurs when executing Select to Oracle's sys tables, especially fetching information for SCHEMA_MIGRATIONS table

My Gemfile:

```
ruby '2.0.0'
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
gem 'activerecord-session_store'
gem 'net-ldap'
gem "composite_primary_keys", :require =>'composite_primary_keys'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'therubyracer' #, '0.11.0beta5'
gem 'libv8', '~> 3.11.8'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'rails-observers'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
group :oracle do
  gem 'ruby-oci8'
  gem 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter'
end
gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

Server Console:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.2 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2013-12-30 16:53:26] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2013-12-30 16:53:26] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-11-22) [i686-linux]
[2013-12-30 16:53:26] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=22522 port=3000


Started GET "/" for nnn.nn.nn.nnn at 2013-12-30 16:53:55 +0100
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "SCHEMA_MIGRATIONS".* FROM "SCHEMA_MIGRATIONS"
   (2.7ms)  SELECT column_name AS name, data_type AS sql_type, data_default, nullable, virtual_column, hidden_column, data_type_owner AS sql_type_owner, DECODE(data_type, 'NUMBER', data_precision, 'FLOAT', data_precision, 'VARCHAR2', DECODE(char_used, 'C', char_length, data_length), 'RAW', DECODE(char_used, 'C', char_length, data_length), 'CHAR', DECODE(char_used, 'C', char_length, data_length), NULL) AS limit, DECODE(data_type, 'NUMBER', data_scale, NULL) AS scale FROM all_tab_cols WHERE owner = '-----' AND table_name = 'SCHEMA_MIGRATIONS' AND hidden_column = 'NO' ORDER BY column_id
  Primary Key (34.2ms)  SELECT cc.column_name FROM all_constraints c, all_cons_columns cc WHERE c.owner = '-----' AND c.table_name = 'SCHEMA_MIGRATIONS' AND c.constraint_type = 'P' AND cc.owner = c.owner AND cc.constraint_name = c.constraint_name

ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)):
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:89:in `initialize'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:89:in `new'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:89:in `action_methods'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/hide_actions.rb:36:in `action_methods'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/url_for.rb:25:in `action_methods'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:179:in `action_method?'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:230:in `method_for_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/hide_actions.rb:17:in `method_for_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:14:in `method_for_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:130:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:680:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'.......
```

Comment: Why, oh why, do developers develop on one database and deploy on another expecting things to work as is? Would you develop using windows/rubinius and deploy on a platform running freebsd/jruby and expect it to work as is? Of course not. The same is true of database engines. They speak very different dialects, and can't agree on even simple things such as `limit` or `autoincrement`. If you deploy on Linux/Oracle, develop using Linux/Oracle. Or at the very least, unit test on it before deploying.

Comment: Well is not exactly as you say: At work, I develop  and deploy with Linux and Oracle. But at home, I use my Mac and Postgres local database, why? becouse is easy and Postgres is free.

Comment: Furthermore, it is useful to use multiple systems to determine where the errors are. Now, for example, I have a clue that the error is behind the DB.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved.

I don't know what was happening exactly, but the solution was get back to the older version of RoR, thanks `git branch` and rvm, and execute again Bundle update and Bundle install.

Comment: you did not face the problem

Comment: I know the problem was arround a bad mixing of ruby/rails and gems versions. With this solution I realized than the gems and my code was ok, what was not ok, probably was using ruby 1.8.7 with gems not prepared with ruby less than 1.9

Comment: Probably the error was creating the development database in a prior version of Rails, and try to create the production database through migrations, with the newest Rails version.